# Can I temporarily mount a partitioned hard drive while using LVM?

Tags: linux-mint, mount, partition, lvm, ssd

I currently have a hard drive with a boot partition and an extended partition; the extended partition contains `/`, swap, and `/home` partitions, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: partition table]

I recently acquired a new 1TB drive and I'm planning to install a new OS. I want to use [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) for flexibility. However, I need to get all the data that's on my current `/home` partition onto the new disk somehow.

If I use [LVM](https://opensource.com/business/16/9/linux-users-guide-lvm) on the new drive and then install the OS (Linux Mint, if that's relevant), can I somehow temporarily mount my existing (partitioned, non-[LVM](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm)) drive to copy the data over? (I do not want to include the old drive in my storage pool, or at least not yet. I'm still figuring out what to do with the old drive, which is partly why I want the flexibility of [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)).)

Comment: @K7AAY I appreciate the added links, but do any of them answer my specific question? (I've read a few tutorials already but didn't see this particular question addressed anywhere, which was why I asked here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Mint (and Ubuntu, and [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/LVM)) will allow you to have multiple drives with different partitioning, e.g., LVM on one physical drive and ext4 on another. It's just another partition; LVM coexists with ext4 just like ZFS can coexist with a different device formatted for ext4. The Debian link in the first line here shows LVM co-existing with non-LVM /boot, and that's as authoritative as they come.

[LVM is explained here](https://opensource.com/article/18/11/manage-storage-lvm), as well as on the five web links under every instance of LVM which were added to your original question.

You may also eliminate the swap partition and [use a swap file instead](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/08/how-to-use-swap-file-instead-of-swap.html), as the performance penalty for a swap file has been resolved.

Comment: This worked seamlessly, thank you. I used LVM and full-disk encryption on the new disk, and the old disks show up and can be mounted normally. Much appreciated.